# How to enforce a phantom read in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, transaction-isolation, phantom-read

I'm currently writing an article about different transaction isolation levels and want to show the dirty read / non-repeatable read / phantom read.

Dirty reads are impossible to show as PostgreSQL does not have READ_UNCOMMITTED, I do have an example for a non-repeatable read. However, I struggle with finding an example for a phantom read.

As an example, I create this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE balances (id varchar PRIMARY KEY, balance int);
INSERT INTO balances (id, balance) VALUES ('Alice', 40), ('Bob', 50);
```

Then I have two terminals (T1 and T2) with which I connect to the database to do this:

```sql
T1$ start transaction isolation level repeatable read;
T1$ SELECT * FROM balances WHERE balance > 10;
    id    | balance 
----------+---------
 Alice    |     40
 Bob      |     50

T2$ INSERT INTO balances (id, balance) VALUES ('Charlie', 60);
T1$ SELECT * FROM balances WHERE balance > 10;

    id    | balance 
----------+---------
 Alice    |     40
 Bob      |     50
```

Why does this not give a phantom read? I thought the last T1-Query should show Charlie, but it doesn't. I thought that would only be the case with the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level. Does REPEATABLE READ also prevent phantom reads in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres 12, the REPEATABLE_READ transaction isolation level prevents phantom reads ([source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In **PostgreSQL**, **`REPEATABLE_READ`** prevents **phantom read**. This is [**my answer on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043712/what-is-the-difference-between-non-repeatable-read-and-phantom-read/73812058#73812058) which has the example of **phantom read** and this is also [**my answer on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55516644/postgresqls-repeatable-read-allows-phantom-reads-but-its-document-says-that-it/74104386#74104386) which experiments if **phantom read** occurs in **`REPEATABLE READ`** in **PostgreSQL**.