# "Non-repeatable read" and "phantom read" occur with 'SERIALIZABLE' isolation level (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, isolation-level, phantom-read

I experimented if **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** occur or not with **SERIALIZABLE** on **MySQL** but against my expectation, both **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** actually occurred with **SERIALIZABLE**.

These below are the definitions of **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read**:

- **Non-repeatable read(fuzzy read)** is the read of committed updated data during a transaction.
- **Phantom read** is the read of committed inserted or deleted data during a transaction.

For my experiment, I set **SERIALIZABLE** globally and sessionly as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation, @@SESSION.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation | @@SESSION.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| SERIALIZABLE                   | SERIALIZABLE                    |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

And, **autocommit** is enabled by default as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@autocommit;
+--------------+
| @@autocommit |
+--------------+
|            1 |
+--------------+
```

And, **InnoDB** is set by default as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test';
+------------+--------+
| TABLE_NAME | ENGINE |
+------------+--------+
| person     | InnoDB |
+------------+--------+
```

And, I used **"person" table** with **"id"** and **"name"** as shown below:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

Fisrt, for **non-repeatable read**, I did **these steps below** with **MySQL queries**. *I used **MySQL version 8.0.30** and **2 command prompts**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Tom' WHERE id = 2;`** |  | **T1 updates "David" to "Tom".** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 cannot read "person" table where "id" is `2`. T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit.** |
| **Step 5** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 2;`** **2 Tom** | **Now, T2 can read "person" table where "id" is 2 but T2 reads "Tom" instead of "David".** #### *Non-repeatable read occurs!! |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

Second, for **phantom read**, I did **these steps below** with **MySQL queries**. *I used **MySQL version 8.0.30** and **2 command prompts**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Tom');`** |  | **T1 inserts the row with `3` and `Tom` to "person" table.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** | **T2 cannot read "person" table. T2 is waiting for T1 to commit.** |
| **Step 5** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 David** **3 Tom** | **Now, T2 can read "person" table but T2 reads 3 rows instead of 2 rows.** #### *Phantom read occurs!! |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

So, is it impossible to prevent **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** with **SERIALIZABLE** on **MySQL**?

Answer (score 0):

This is a side-effect of InnoDB's locking reads. Locking reads always read the most recently committed data, so they work as if you used READ COMMITTED isolation level. Therefore the view of the data in a given transaction (your T2 transaction above, for example), may view new data that wasn't committed at the time the transaction began.

InnoDB implements SERIALIZABLE by implicitly making every `SELECT` query a locking read, as if you had used `FOR SHARE` (the same clause was known as `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` before MySQL 8.0). Therefore all queries are locking reads, and always query in the read-committed fashion.

This is unfortunately in conflict with the documented claim that SERIALIZABLE is like REPEATABLE READ. It isn't, unless you use autocommit mode and therefore a `SELECT` is non-locking because it's known to be in a read-only transaction.

This is by design in InnoDB. No, there's no way to prevent it, without switching to a different storage engine or a different brand of database.

There is one other method to get a true serializable transaction: use explicit `LOCK TABLES` statements to implement pessimistic locking. This will ensure only one transaction at a time has access to the table, but it will hinder concurrency.

---

I don't know of a storage engine available for MySQL that supports transactions and prevents phantom reads. Certainly not any of the storage engines provided in a default installation of MySQL.

Of course a non-transactional storage engine like MyISAM or MEMORY doesn't have the phantom read problem, because there's no such thing as uncommitted data in a non-transactional read problem. But I don't suggest using these storage engines, because they don't support ACID properties.

Facebook makes a transactional storage engine called RocksDB, but I can't find documentation on its handling of transaction isolation levels.

Other storage engines shipped with MySQL do not support transactions at all.

I've used one other specific RDBMS that prevents phantom reads: InterBase, aka Firebird. But you probably won't like the solution.

In InterBase, in the example like the one you describe in your question, transaction T2 will block, waiting for T1 to resolve. If T1 rolls back, then T2 can read the rows. The result in T2 is the same as the state of data when T2 began, because the new row was rolled back by T1. But if T1 commits, then T2 *cannot* read the data, because it would make its view inconsistent. So T2 gets an error.

This is kind of awful. T2 has to wait for T1 to resolve, then eventually gets an error anyway. That's adding insult to injury!

But it does prevent phantom reads.

I think InnoDB was implemented the way it was because the alternative solution used in InterBase was not liked by most people.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's possible to prevent both **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** with `SERIALIZABLE` on **MySQL**. In addition, you can also prevent both **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** with `REPEATABLE READ` which is the default isolation level on **MySQL**.

**The table below** shows which problems occur in **each isolation level** on **MySQL** according to my experiments. *`Yes` means ***Occurs***, `No` means ***Doesn't occur***:

| Isolation Level | Dirty Read | Non-Repeatable Read | Phantom Read |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **No** | **Yes** | **Yes** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **No** | **No** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** | **No** | **No** |

Actually, your definitions below of **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** are wrong and your experiment steps are also wrong:

> - **Non-repeatable read(fuzzy read)** is the read of committed updated data during a transaction.
> - **Phantom read** is the read of committed inserted or deleted data during a transaction.

These below are the correct definitions of **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read**:

- **Non-repeatable read(fuzzy read)** is that a transaction reads the same row at least twice but the same row's data is different between the 1st and 2nd reads because other transactions update the same row's data and commit at the same time(concurrently).
- **Phantom read** is that a transaction reads the same table at least twice but the number of the same table's rows is different between the 1st and 2nd reads because other transactions insert or delete rows and commit at the same time(concurrently).

And these below are the experiments of **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** with the correct steps. Actually in the experiments below with `SERIALIZABLE`, **non-repeatable read** and **phantom read** don't occur so if you want to see that they occur, see [What is the difference between Non-Repeatable Read and Phantom Read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043712/what-is-the-difference-between-non-repeatable-read-and-phantom-read/73812058#73812058) which has my answer with the experiments with `READ COMMITTED` to occur them.

For my experiment, I set `SERIALIZABLE` as shown below:

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation, @@SESSION.transaction_isolation;
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.transaction_isolation | @@SESSION.transaction_isolation |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| SERIALIZABLE                   | SERIALIZABLE                    |
+--------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

And, I used **`person` table** with **`id`** and **`name`** as shown below.

#### `person` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **David** |

Fisrt, for **non-repeatable read**, I did **these correct steps below** with **MySQL queries**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = 2;`** **2 David** |  | **T1 reads `David`.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Tom' WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to update `David` to `Tom`.** #### *Non-repeatable read cannot occur!! |
| **Step 5** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`UPDATE person SET name = 'Tom' WHERE id = 2;`** | **Now, T2 can update `David` to `Tom`.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |

Second, for **phantom read**, I did **these correct steps below** with **MySQL queries**:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT * FROM person;`** **1 John** **2 David** |  | **T2 read `person` table.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Tom');`** | **T2 needs to wait for T1 to commit to insert the row with `3` and `Tom` to `person` table.** #### *Phantom read cannot occur!! |
| **Step 5** | **`COMMIT;`** | **Waiting...** | **T1 commits.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Tom');`** | **Now, T2 can insert the row with `3` and `Tom` to `person` table.** |
| **Step 7** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |