# "Read skew" vs "Non-repeatable read" (Transaction)

Tags: database, transactions, isolation-level, non-repeatable-read

I read [**A beginner’s guide to Read and Write Skew phenomena**](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-read-and-write-skew-phenomena/) and [**A beginner’s guide to Non-Repeatable Read anomaly**](https://vladmihalcea.com/non-repeatable-read/) below to know what **read skew** and **non-repeatable read** are.

**Read skew**:

[image]

**Non-repeatable read**:

[image]

But, I cannot differentiate between **read skew** and **non-repeatable read** and basically, it seems like both can be prevented with **`REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level**.

My questions:

1. What is the difference between **read skew** and **non-repeatable
   read**?
2. Can **read skew** and **non-repeatable read** be both prevented by **`REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`**?

Answer (score 4):

- **Non-repeatable read(fuzzy read)** is that a transaction reads the same row at least twice but the same row's data is different between the 1st and 2nd reads because other transactions update the same row's data and commit at the same time(concurrently). *I explain more about **non-repeatable read** in [**What is the difference between Non-Repeatable Read and Phantom Read?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043712/what-is-the-difference-between-non-repeatable-read-and-phantom-read/73812058#73812058)
- **Read skew** is that with two different queries, a transaction reads  inconsistent data because between the 1st and 2nd queries, other transactions insert, update or delete data and commit. Finally, an inconsistent result is produced by the inconsistent data.

There are the examples of **read skew** below which you can do with **MySQL** and **2 command prompts**.

For these examples of **read skew** below, you need to set **`READ COMMITTED` isolation level** to occur **read skew**:

```
SET GLOBAL TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
```

And, there is **`bank_account` table** with **`id`**, **`name`** and **`balance`** as shown below.

#### `bank_account` table:

| id | name | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** | **600** |
| **2** | **Tom** | **400** |

**These steps below** shows **read skew**. *`300` is transferred from John's balance to Tom's balance. Then from Tom's balance, T1 reads `100(Inconsistent data)` instead of `400`. Finally, `600` + `100` = `700(Inconsistent result)` in the total of John's and Tom's balances:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT balance FROM bank_account WHERE id = 1;`** **600** |  | **T1 reads `600`.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE bank_account set balance = 900 WHERE id = 1;`** | **T2 updates `600` to `900` because `300` is transferred from Tom's balance.** |
| **Step 5** |  | **`UPDATE bank_account set balance = 100 WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `400` to `100` because `300` is transferred to John's balance.** |
| **Step 6** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 7** | **`SELECT balance FROM bank_account WHERE id = 2;`** **100** |  | **T1 reads `100(Inconsistent data)` instead of `400` after T2 commits.** |
| **Step 8** | **600 + 100 = 700** |  | **Finally, T1 gets `700(Inconsistent result)` instead of `1000`.** #### *Read skew occurs. |
| **Step 9** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |

**These steps below** also shows **read skew**. *`300` is withdrawn from Tom's balance. Then, T1 reads `100(Inconsistent data)` instead of `400`. Finally, `600` + `100` = `700(Inconsistent result)` in the total of John's and Tom's balances:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT balance FROM bank_account WHERE id = 1;`** **600** |  | **T1 reads `600`.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`UPDATE bank_account set balance = 100 WHERE id = 2;`** | **T2 updates `400` to `100` because `300` is withdrawn from Tom's balance.** |
| **Step 5** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 6** | **`SELECT balance FROM bank_account WHERE id = 2;`** **100** |  | **T1 reads `100(Inconsistent data)` instead of `400` after T2 commits.** |
| **Step 7** | **600 + 100 = 700** |  | **Finally, T1 gets `700(Inconsistent result)` instead of `1000`.** #### *Read skew occurs. |
| **Step 8** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |

In addition, this is also the example of **read skew**. There are **`teacher` and `student` tables** with **`id`**, **`name`** as shown below.

#### `teacher` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **John** |
| **2** | **Tom** |

#### `student` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| **1** | **Anna** |
| **2** | **Sarah** |
| **3** | **David** |
| **4** | **Mark** |
| **5** | **Kai** |

**These steps below** shows **read skew**. *`Lisa`, `Peter` and `Roy` are inserted to **"student" table**. Then, T1 reads `8(Inconsistent data)` instead of `5`. Finally, `2` + `8` = `9(Inconsistent result)` in the total of teachers and students:

| Flow | Transaction 1 (T1) | Transaction 2 (T2) | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Step 1** | **`BEGIN;`** |  | **T1 starts.** |
| **Step 2** |  | **`BEGIN;`** | **T2 starts.** |
| **Step 3** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM teacher;`** **2** |  | **T1 reads `2`.** |
| **Step 4** |  | **`INSERT INTO student values (6, 'Lisa'), (7, 'Peter'), (8, 'Roy');`** | **T2 inserts `Lisa`, `Peter` and `Roy`.** |
| **Step 5** |  | **`COMMIT;`** | **T2 commits.** |
| **Step 6** | **`SELECT count(*) FROM student;`** **8** |  | **T1 reads `8(Inconsistent data)` instead of `5` after T2 commits.** |
| **Step 7** | **2 + 8 = 10** |  | **Finally, T1 gets `10(Inconsistent result)` instead of `7`.** #### *Read skew occurs!! |
| **Step 8** | **`COMMIT;`** |  | **T1 commits.** |

These tables below are my experiment results of **read skew** with each isolation level in **MySQL** and **PostgreSQL**. ***`Yes`** means ***Occurs***, **`No`** means ***Doesn't occur***.

**MySQL**:

| Isolation level | Read skew |
| --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **Yes** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** |

**PostgreSQL**:

| Isolation level | Read skew |
| --- | --- |
| **READ UNCOMMITTED** | **Yes** |
| **READ COMMITTED** | **Yes** |
| **REPEATABLE READ** | **No** |
| **SERIALIZABLE** | **No** |

Comment: Can I say that read skew (general case) includes both non-repeatable read and phantom read (special cases)? I believe there isn't a clear definition for the concept of read skew.

(Also, thanks Kai for actively explaining various data anomalies using specific step-by-step examples.)

Answer (score 1):

**1. What is the difference between read skew and non-repeatable read?**

We have two data - let **x** and **y**, and there is a relation between them.(e.g parent/child)

Transaction T1 reads **x**, and then a second transaction T2 updates **x** and **y** to new values and commits. If now T1 reads **y**, it may see an inconsistent state, and therefore produce an inconsistent state as output.

Acceptable consistent states:

*x and y*

*x and *y

*Note: * denotes the updated value of the variable*

When x and y are the same data, meaning to read them, need to execute the same query.
I guess, it leads to the problem of non-repeatable.

IMHO, even if we may call read skew is a generalization form of a non-repeatable problem.

**2. Can read skew and non-repeatable read be both prevented by **REPEATABLE READ** or **SERIALIZABLE**?**

**Serializable isolation level** permits transactions to run concurrently, it creates the effect that transactions are running in serial order: *read skew/non-repeatable prevented*

**Repeatable read isolation level** guarantees that each transaction will return the same row regardless of how many times executed.
From the definition, it seems read-skew may not be prevented.
Without knowing how it is implemented, it is hard to claim anything.

Today, DBMS engines use different approaches-concurrency control strategies to implement **REPEATABLE Isolation level**.

*e.g Postgres use database snapshot(consistent view) to implement **REPEATABLE READ Isolation level**: it will prevent read skew*

*Other engines may use lock-based concurrency control mechanisms to implement it. - may not prevent read skew.*