# Avoide race conditions in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, race-condition, select-for-update

I am concerned about race conditions in my database backed application. My application allows users to reserve a spot in a class. If all the spots are taken, then they are placed on a wait list. In greatly simplified pseudo code, I'm doing something like:

```
1  spots = SELECT total_spots FROM classes WHERE class_id = 200;
2  regs  = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registrations WHERE class_id = 200;
3  wl    = spots > regs
4  INSERT INTO registrations ( user_id, class_id, on_waitlist ) VALUES ( 500, 200, wl );
```

What happens if `total_spots` is changed in the `classes` table, or another user does an INSERT on the `registrations` table just after we read it (row 2).

Is it adequate to wrap the entire thing in a transaction? I've read a little about `SELECT FOR UPDATE` in MySQL. I'm currently using SQLite, but I can migrate to MySQL if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's transactions [are fully atomic](http://www.sqlite.org/transactional.html).

If you wrap the entire thing in a transaction, other connections to the same database cannot make any changes at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't that just guarantee that all **updates** are performed or rolled back. As I read the SQLite [docs](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), inside a transaction you get a `SHARED` lock at the first read and a `RESERVED` lock at the first write. Can't another process write while you are holding the `SHARED` lock (ie, just before the update in line 4)?

Comment: A shared lock prevents anybody else from acquiring a reserved lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can also select within your insert:

```
insert into registrations (user_id, class_id, on_waitlist) 
 values ( 500, 200,
   (SELECT total_spots FROM classes WHERE class_id = 200) <  
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM registrations WHERE class_id = 200)
 );
```

Comment: This would be my preferred way to deal with it, but the example I gave is greatly simplified. There are many checks that are preformed before allowing the registration. I'm not sure I can get them all in one statement.

Comment: Then transactions are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experiments in SQLite, race conditions don't occur so [lost update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew#73847878) and [write skew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826714/lost-update-vs-write-skew#73847878) don't occur because the isolation level is `SERIALIZABLE` (default) and even if the isolation level is `READ UNCOMMITTED` which is strange. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370947/reading-uncommitted-changes-dirty-read-from-sqlite-database/74079973#74079973) explains it more.